# Overlaying Lines in Matplotlib Graph?

Tags: matplotlib, data-visualization

I'm trying to print a simple line graph where the output in tracking imdbRating over time of different seasons from a show. I have my code entered like this:

```
S1imdb = season_1['imdbRating']
S2imdb = season_2['imdbRating']
S3imdb = season_3['imdbRating']
S4imdb = season_4['imdbRating']
S5imdb = season_5['imdbRating']
S6imdb = season_6['imdbRating']
S7imdb = season_7['imdbRating']
S8imdb = season_8['imdbRating']
S9imdb = season_9['imdbRating']


plt.plot(S1imdb, label = "Season 1")
plt.plot(S2imdb, label = 'Season 2')
plt.plot(S3imdb, label = 'Season 3')
plt.plot(S4imdb, label = 'Season 4')
plt.plot(S5imdb, label = 'Season 5')
plt.plot(S6imdb, label = 'Season 6')
plt.plot(S7imdb, label = 'Season 7')
plt.plot(S8imdb, label = 'Season 8')
plt.plot(S9imdb, label = 'Season 9')
plt.show()
```

and my output is this:

[Plot of IMDB Rating + Season Numebr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Poo.png)

However, I'd like these lines to be mapped on top of each other as opposed to next to each other. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may create new x coordinates from the lengths of the dataframes.

```
seasons = [season_1, season_2, season_3, season_4, ...]

for i, season in enumerate(seasons):
    y = season['imdbRating']
    x = range(1, len(y)+1)
    plt.plot(x, y, label = "Season {}".format(i+1))
```

Comment: Thanks! Totally worked. I didn't think about how terrible it would be to lay these lines over each other though. 9 lines of different colors looks terrible next to each other like this lol.

Comment: Any reason to start the range from 1 and then add 1 instead of default 0 start and len(y) as the end?

Comment: @Bazingaa Yes there is some very profound thought behind this :-). I interpreted the x axis denoting the episode number inside the season. Since the first episode should get the number 1, I would think it makes sense to start with 1 and not 0. Seeing a dip in the diagram at the number 9 would then directly tell you that episode No. 9 was badly received.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: You should in that case label the first x-tick as `'Pilot'` ;)